# Can MS Access pass credentials to an SSRS report/data source?

Tags: ms-access, reporting-services, office365, sql-server-2019, ssrs-2019

Right now, I have a security system implemented in Access where certain users can open certain reports. If you don't have access to the report, then you can't see the button for it. The object explorer pane on the left is locked down.

I now want to move everything to SSRS, but still keep using the same Access security I already have set up. I can't use Windows auth security since the end users share 1 Windows login, so I need to find a way to accomplish 2 things:

1. Pass up credentials to the SSRS report/the data source through the button click
2. Don't store the credentials in the URL so that the users can't share a report via the link alone

Below is the code to open the SSRS report via Access VBA.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

   Dim strUrl As String

   strUrl = "http://sql1/ReportS/report/Report1"
   CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open CVar(strUrl)


End Sub
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816251/how-to-pass-credentials-when-accessing-ssrs-report-through-url

Comment: @June7 no because this stores the credentials in the URL. I can't show that info in the report URL